# Ubuntu virtualbox

Tags: system-installation

I have ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64 iso file on my pc with win 7.when I try to install it on virtual box using optical ide disk controller I allot dynamic memory giving more than 20 gb space.but while starting the installation it shows I need to have atleast 6.6 gb space.I cannot understand whats going on.

Comment: Did you allocate 20 GB RAM  memory or 20 GB virtual hard drive space on creating a VDI?

Answer (score 0):

6.6 GB is **minimum requirement** for Ubuntu. The 20GB that you allocate are to create virtual hard drive. It's like you said "Here virtual box, I am going to give you 20 GB hard drive, and install something there."

The installer always checks if you have enough space on disk to install the base system. That means you are going to have 20 - 6.6 GB = 13.4 GB free for your personal needs

I personally allocate just 8 GB for Ubuntu in virtualbox because I don't install that much software there, but depending on your needs you can get there more or less, as long as it's not bellow 6.6 GB.

Comment: I allocated to virtual hard drive space. and it is dynamic

Comment: @sabsac dynamic means you can change it later. It doesn't mean it will be resized automatically